# OOP PHP - proper way to pass $_POST values from form to database_write function

Tags: php, database, forms

I have trouble understanding OOP...

Lets say I wanted to create a page that adds a new user to a database and wanted to work with classes.

For that scenario i'd create a form with a function.

There are forms for each CRUD functionality - renderHTMLFormAddUser() :

```
...
        <form action="" method="POST" >;

        <label>Shopname*</label><br>;
        <input type="text" name="shopname" class="input_wide" required><br>;
        <label>Username*</label><br>;
        <input type="text" name="username" class="input_wide" required><br>;

        <input type="submit" value="add" name="submit" >
...
```

a DataBaseConnector class:

```
class DataBaseConnector
{
        protected $con;

        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->con=mysqli_connect('mariaDB','root','123456','produktmuster');
        }

        public function getConnection()
        {
            return $this->con;
        }

        public function __destruct()
        {
            $this->con->close();
        }
}
```

and a QueryDatabase class that requires the DataBaseConnector connection as a transfer parameter in its constructor:

```
class QueryDatabase
{

    private $con;

    public function __construct(DataBaseConnector $con)
    {
        $this->con = $con;
    }


    public function addUser($shopname,$username)
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `brandportal_manager`( `Shopname`, `Username`) VALUES  ($shopname,$username)";
        $result = mysqli_query($this->con->connect(), $sql);
        return $result;
    }
```

To get the $_POST values in the QueryDatabase add User function, i'd need to declare variables like so:

```
$shopname= $_POST['shopname'];
$username= $_POST['username'];
```

But is there a better way to do so? 
Like maybe `renderHTMLFormAddUser()->'shopname'`.

Im just trying to understand what is the cleanest way to code in this scenario.
Because using a function to render the forms the adduser.php would look something like this:

```
$createuserform=new Forms();
$createuserform->renderHTMLFormAddUser();

$shopname= $_POST['shopname'];  // this is what confuses me, you'd have to look into the
$username= $_POST['username']; //  renderHTMLFormAddUser() function to see the code

$db = new DataBaseConnector();
$query= new QueryDatabase();
$query->addUser($shopname,$username)
```

Should I just create an own page that posts the form to a page that then uses the data?
In the beginning i simply used no transfer parameters with the addUser function, and it started with declaring the $_POSTs:

```
$shopname= $_POST['shopname'];
$username= $_POST['username'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO `brandportal_manager`( `Shopname`, `Username`) VALUES  ($shopname,$username)";
...
```

But I was told it was unsafe to do so - in that regard, I sanitize my data but for the sake of easier example i stripped away all the unnecessary code.

Should I take a completely different approach, just would like to know the cleanest way to add form input data into a database.

Comment: the point is to use **prepared statements** when posting value from a form. This is the only way to sanitize your data properly. It is not related to **how** you access the data but on the manipulation you do **before** injecting them into the query. Mysqli supports prepared statements

Comment: see [php documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) for examples on how prepared statements work

Comment: Thank you, I am aware that I need to use prepared statements on the DB input values, but I wanted to know how to avoid the $_POST appearence outside the function. I actually had prepared statements in the code, but I stripped everything not question related, so that the post was less of a wall of text :) .

Comment: to answer your question: _ "just would like to know the cleanest way to add form input data into a database"_ the answer is "using prepared statements". `$_POST` is fine in your code

Comment: Okay thanks, I thought it was not!

Answer (score -3):

Well, there are many approaches to do this. You can also do my OOPs approach:

Make a define.php to set the constant variables & database connection variables:
**define.php**

```
define("DB_HOSTNAME", "localhost");
define("DB_USERNAME", "your_username");
define("DB_PASSWORD", "your_password");
define("DB_NAME", "your_databasename");
define("custom_variable", "custom_variable_value");
define("baseurl", "https://localhost/myproject/");
```

Then, make dbase.php, to create a dynamic SQL function:

You don't need to change this file. You just need to call this class. This file work as the core file of the system.
**Dbase.php**

```
<?php session_start();
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Karachi");
require_once("define.php");

Class Dbase
{
    private $Host = DB_HOSTNAME;
    private $UserName = DB_USERNAME;
    private $Password = DB_PASSWORD;
    private $DBname = DB_NAME;

    private $connDb = false;

    public $LastQuery = null;
    public $AffectedRows = 0;
    public $InsertKey = array();
    public $InsertValues = array();
    public $UpdateSets = array();

    public $id;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->connect();
    }

    protected function connect()
    {
        $this->connDb = @mysqli_connect($this->Host, $this->UserName, $this->Password);
        if (!($this->connDb)) {
            die('Database Connection Failed.<br>' . mysql_error($this->connDb));
        } else {
            $Select = mysqli_select_db($this->connDb,$this->DBname);
            if (!$Select) {
                die('Database Selection Failed.<br>' . mysql_error($this->connDb));
            }
        }

        mysqli_set_charset($this->connDb,'utf8');
    }

    public function close()
    {
        if (!mysqli_close($this->connDb)) {
            die('Closing Connection Failed.<br>');
        }
    }

    public function escape($value)
    {
        if (function_exists('mysql_real_escape_string')) {
            if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
                $value = stripslashes($value);
            }
            $value = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
        } else {
            if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
                $value = addcslashes($value);
            }
        }
        return $value;
    }


    public function query($sql)
    {
        $query = $sql;
        $result = mysqli_query($this->connDb,$sql);
//        $this->displayQuery($result);
        return $result;
    }

    public function displayQuery($result)
    {
        if (!$result) {
            $output = 'Database Query Failed' . mysql_error($this->connDb) . '<br>';
            $output .= 'Last Query was' . $this->LastQuery;
            die($output);
        } else {
            $this->AffectedRows = mysqli_affected_rows($this->connDb);
        }
    }

    public function fetchAll($sql)
    {
        $result = $this->query($sql);
        $output = array();
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $output[] = $row;
        }
//        mysql_free_result($result);
        return $output;
    }

    public function fetchOne($sql)
    {
        $output = $this->fetchAll($sql);
        return $output;
//        return array_shift($output);
    }

    public function prepareInsert($array = null)
    {
        if (!empty($array)) {
            foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
                $this->InsertKey[] = $key;
                $this->InsertValues[] = $this->escape($value);
            }
        }
    }

    public function insert($table = null)
    {
        if (!empty($table) && !empty($this->InsertKey) && !empty($this->InsertValues)) {
            $sql = "insert into '{$table}' ('";
            $sql .= implode("','", $this->InsertKey);
            $sql .= "') values ('";
            $sql .= implode("','", $this->InsertValues);
            $sql .= "')";

            if ($this->query($sql)) {
                $this->id = $this->lastId();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function prepareUpdate($array = null)
    {
        if (!empty($array)) {
            foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
                $this->UpdateSets[] = "`{$key}` = '" . $this->escape($value) . "'";
            }
        }
    }


    public function update($table = null, $id = null, $whereId)
    {
        if (!empty($table) && !empty($id) && !empty($this->UpdateSets)) {
            $sql = "update `{$table}` set";
            $sql .= implode(",", $this->UpdateSets);
//            $sql.="where id='".$this->escape($id)."'";
            $sql .= "where '" . $whereId . "'='" . $this->escape($id) . "'";
            return $this->query($sql);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }


    public function lastId()
    {
        return mysqli_insert_id($this->connDb);
    }

    public function TotalNumberOfRecords($sql)
    {
        $result = $this->query($sql);
        $output = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        return $output;
    }


    public function GetServerInfo()
    {
        return mysqli_get_server_info();
    }
}
```

Create a Query.php file. This file work as your model file as in MVC.
**Query.php**

```
<?php include "Dbase.php";

Class Query extends Dbase
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->connect();
        date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Karachi");
    }

    public function getData($idlevelOne)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` where level_one_id=$idlevelOne ORDER BY `sorting` ASC";
        $result = $this->fetchAll($sql);
        return $result;
    }

    /*For Insert & Edit, use this fucntion*/
    public function editMember($email, $phone, $address, $city, $country, $zipcode, $id)
    {
        $sql = "UPDATE `members` SET  `email` = '" . $email . "', `phone` = '" . $phone . "', `address` = '" . $address . "'
            , `city` = '" . $city . "', `country` = '" . $country . "', `zip_code` = '" . $zipcode . "'
    WHERE   `id` = '$id'";
        $result = $this->query($sql);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Now, you just need to call the Query class in your PHP files to get the data.

```
    <?php 
    include "Query.php";
    $ObjQuery = new Query(); 
    $ObjQuery->getData(1);
```

Comment: your code is open to SQL injections. You don't use prepared statements and thus lead to a severe security breach on your application. Even if for internal use this can eventually lead to data corruptions

Comment: also you are mixing mysqli_* and mysql_* api that will prevent your application from working properly

Comment: And you're not using a singleton class instance to prevent multiple DB connections. This is not a good answer at all

Comment: yeah. there are many things which is required in this code. This is just a sample code.